# Как на iOS реализовать работу с WebSocket?

Tags: objective-c, ios, iphone

Всем добрый вечер. Мой вопрос: Мне необходимо сконектится с WebSocket на iPhone(X-Studio). На сегодня сервер работает как эхо, то есть возвращает посланное, и мне бы хотелось проверить это через мое iOS приложение. Я прочел пару статей на эту тему, но пока ничего не получилось! Так вот чтобы открыть соединение с сокетом на JavaScript это делается так new Websocket('ws://ofs.ft-ru.ru:8080'). Как мне это сделать на iOS, и при этом отправить и получить что нибудь? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте эту библиотеку [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket)